# Fastest way to filter data from Drupal Backend in Frontend

Tags: php, angular, drupal

I am using front-end in Angular, but i need to use the search engine in drupal 9 to access the database instead of using the JSONAPI or bring data in JSON format, because it takes to long to retrieve the data.

This is the code in service

```
export interface InformesCounter {
  data: any;
  meta: any;
  count: any;
  attributes: any;
  titulo: any[];
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FrontService {
  countInformes = 'http://localhost/webagn2019/jsonapi/node/informes?filter[title][operator]=CONTAINS&filter[title][value]';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getInformes(): Observable<InformesCounter> {
    return this.http.get<InformesCounter>(this.countInformes)
    .pipe(
      retry(3),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

And this in my component.ts

```
  showInformes() {
  this.frontService.getInformes()
      .subscribe((data: InformesCounter) => {
        this.informesCount = data.meta;
        this.informesTitle = data.data;
        this.titleList = this.informesTitle.map((data: { attributes: { titulo: any; }; }) => data.attributes.titulo);
        this.onSubmit();
        console.log(this.titleList);
      });
  }
```

Like you see i use httpget to retrive the data in JSON format and display into the front-end but it takes time to bring more than 2000objects with all the attributes and properties of each one. I know there must be a way to display de data of the backend into the Angular Frontend. But i don't have a clue how to do this.

I will appreciate any help you can provide me.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking help for.

Comment: I have a large data, and i need to retrieve from the database into my front-end but the json file with more than 3000 objects is big and takes 30 seconds to one minute to display de data. I need to make a search filter.

Comment: You need to implement paging, or start out with a subset of the data based on some property, such as a created date or something relevant to your use case

Comment: Understood so the right code should be sth like that: informesNodes = 'http://localhost/webagn2019/jsonapi/node/informes?filter'+[Campo]+'='+Valor;